# My while loop won't stop after a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a dice game and you have 3 goes and, if you don't guess it with the 3 goes, it will show you the number and say you lost but for me it only shows it if you don't guess it in 4 goes.

```
import random
import time

guess=3

print ("Welcome to the dice game :) ")
print ("You have 3 guess's all together!")
time.sleep(1)

dice=random.randint(1, 6)

option=int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 6: "))

while option != dice and guess > 0:
    option=int(input("Wrong try again you still have " + str(guess) + " chances remaining: "))
    guess=guess-1

    if guess == 0:
        print ("You lost")
        print ("The number was " + str(dice))

if option == dice:
    print ("You win and got it with " + str(guess) + " guess remaining")
```

and the result is:

```
Welcome to the dice game :) 
You have 3 guess's all together!
Enter a number between 1 and 6: 4
Wrong try again you still have 3 chances remaining: 4
Wrong try again you still have 2 chances remaining: 4
Wrong try again you still have 1 chances remaining: 4
You lost
The number was 2
```

Comment: Have you managed to figure out which part of your program works? Have you tried printing variables to show what is happening? Have you walked through your code with paper and pencil to try and diagnose the problem? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner way to write this would be

```
import random
import time

guesses = 3

print("Welcome to the dice game :) ")
print("You have 3 guesses all together!")
time.sleep(1)

dice = random.randint(1, 6)

while guesses > 0:
    option = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 6: "))
    guesses -= 1

    if option == dice:
        print(f"You win and got it with {guesses} guess(es) remaining")
        break

    if guesses > 0:
        print("Wrong try again you still have {guesses} guess(es) remaining")
else:
    print("You lost")
    print(f"The number was {dice}")
```

The loop condition only tracks the number of guesses remaining. If you guess correctly, use an explicit `break` to exit the loop. The `else` clause on the loop, then, is only executed if you *don't* use an explicit `break`.

Comment: I think you cannot simply call this a cleaner implementation, if your program does not output the same as the original. You are not informing the user properly about the fact that his input was wrong, and you do not inform the user about how many tries he has left. I think this is part of the problem the OP is facing, that he wants to have a different message for the first try then for the retries and then the OP messed up their counter variable. So I think you kind of just cut out the part that is "more difficult" to write in a "clean" manner for beginners.

Comment: That's easy enough to fix.

Comment: Perfect. Looking forward to your improved answer. Will upvote then.

Answer (score 1):

You're giving the user an extra chance with this line: `option=int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 6: "))`. Try declaring `guess=2` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code clearly grants the initial guess (before the loop), and then three more (within the loop).  If you want it to be 3 guesses, then simply reduce your guess counter by 1.